# Dual gate driver inputs/outputs tied together

Tags: gate-driving, igbt

I'm using an [IR4427 dual low-side gate driver](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir4426.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355d60b491822) to drive a single [IXEL40N400 IGBT](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS99385B(IXEL40N400)_.pdf).  Since I'm not using the second side, I'm considering tying its input to the active input and output to the active output for higher current availability and thus, I hope, faster switching.  Does anyone foresee a problem here?  To me it just seems like I'm paralleling two (hopefully well-matched -- they're on the same die) MOSFETs, but I'd like to be certain.

Here's the proposed schematic snippet:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUr3Z7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why do you need a *higher current availability* for ? It's a gate/base driver, no need for any high current there.

Comment: For charging the gate capacitance quicker, and therefore turning on the IGBT quicker.  I don't have a lot of experience with IGBTs, though, so my concern may not be warranted.

Comment: Rdson of the gate driver is already sub 10 ohms so with your series Rg there isn't much to gain anyhow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No worries if you put a 10 ohm resistor on each gate driver output.

Answer (score -1):

One problem with gate-drivers is the input interface with MCUs.

The ESD structures of gate-drivers are connected to the GND rail and to the VDD rail. These rails are bouncy, at the level of 10nH DIP-in-socket and 1amp-per-nanosecond for some larger drivers; the level is V = L * dI/dT, or 10 volts bouncy (that means GND rises UP by 10 volts, and 18volt rail drops to 8 volts).

Thus DIP-packages-in-sockets must not be used. And those white-boards should not be used, if you expect reliable gate-driver behavior.

Now.................the topic is interface with the MCU. What happens at that interface if the gate-driver GND rises by 10 volts (or 3 volts, or 1volt)? If GND rises, the MCU signal is below GND and the gate-driver ESD structure turns on, if a simple diode structure.

Now now........the stored energy causes RINGING, and the gate-driver GND voltage cycles back the other way, heading negative. The MCU output voltage now is the acceptable range, and the gate-driver ESD remains off.

Conclusion-----READ THE GATE-DRIVER datasheet. And understand the gate-driver ESD structure behavior, as the gate-driver GND bounced up and down by 1 volt, or 2 volts, or 3 volts, or 4 volts.

Do you want charges injected into your MCU, several AMPERES of transient current, as your gate-driver switches state?

Why discuss this here? Because using TWO gate-drivers will cause TWICE the GND bounce, and be more likely to dump transient charge into the MCU.

SUMMARY: some gate-drivers use special input ESD arrangements/circuits that tolerate 4 or 5 volts difference in "gnd" between MCU and gate-driver. Some such ICs have 4 or 5 volts tolerance on normal inputs but NOT on "enable" inputs. Which buys you nothing. Examine the datasheet carefully. Call the manufacturer or the field engineer. Ask. Avoid surprises.

Comment: So the down-voter has no experience with gate-drivers?

Comment: On the contrary, I've built a variety of power systems with IGBTs, Si and SiC MOSFETs at scales from 10 W to 40 kW.  Your rambling, incoherent post doesn't answer the question.